# How can you index a discord channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make it so i could index a discord channel using something like !index and it would then index the channel and store it in a variable. How could i do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by "index" the channel? There are plenty of different ways you could do this, and all of those ways can *easily* be found on the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org). Please look at the docs before asking questions here, and tell us what you've tried so far in your question. We are here to help if you truly cannot find the solution you are looking for, but this solution could've been found with a single google search.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! I haven't quite understood what you meant by 'indexing' a channel, but if you just want to store the channel ID (which is the only thing you really need to store), this should help. Also, consider using a DB (`Quick.db` is great for beginners), since the Set is gonna disappear as soon as you stop the program.

```js
let channels  = new Set()
// with msg a Message
if (msg.content === "!index") {
    // get the message's channel id
    const channelId = msg.channel.id
    // store the channel id in the Set
    channels.add(channelId)
}
```

A JavaScript [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is like an array, but with more properties and unique values.
You can find more information on the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org) for D.js and the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for general JS.